# default else statement for thymeleaf if case

Tags: thymeleaf

I know I can use `th:if` and `th:unless` for `if-else` condition on `thymeleaf`. But i am wondering if there are any other way to handle default else without using `th:unless`.

i have if condition like this

```
th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(myList) and condition1 and condition2 and condition3}"
```

now i don't want to repeat same conditions on `th:unless` block. Is there is way to do this without using `th:unless`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, no way to do that with `th:if` -- it affects a single tag only.  There are a couple of more verbose options though:

1. Use `th:with` for your conditions.  For example:

   ```
   <th:block th:with="condition=${not #lists.isEmpty(myList) and condition1 and condition2 and condition3}">
       <div th:if="${condition}" />
       <div th:unless="${condition}" />
   </th:block>
   ```
2. Use `th:switch`. For example:

   ```
   <th:block th:switch="${not #lists.isEmpty(myList) and condition1 and condition2 and condition3}">
     <div th:case="true" />
     <div th:case="*" />
   </th:block>
   ```

Comment: follow up question. can `sec:authorize` be mixed with `th:if` ?

Comment: @user9735824 -- I don't have much experience with Spring Security, but it looks like you can do expressions like this:  `th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}"`. See [these docs](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity#user-content-using-the-expression-utility-objects)